# Hive - the correct way to permanently change the date and type in the entire column

Tags: date, hadoop, hive, ambari, hdp

I would be grateful if someone could explain here step by step what the process of changing the date format and column type from string to date should look like in the table imported via Hive View to HDP 2.6.5.
The data source is the well-known MovieLens 100K Dataset set ('u.item' file) from:
https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/100k/

> $ hive --version is: 1.2.1000.2.6.5.0-292 
> Date format for the column is: '01-Jan-1995' 
> Data type of column is: 'string' 
> ACID Transactions is 'On'

Ultimately, I would like to convert permanently the data in the entire column to the correct Hive format 'yyyy-MM-dd' and next column type to 'Date'. 
I have looked at over a dozen threads regarding similar questions before. Of course, the problem is not to display the column like this, it can be easily done using just:

`SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(prod_date,'dd-MMM-yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd') FROM moviesnames;`

The problem is to finally write it down this way. Unfortunately, this cannot be done via UPDATE in the following way, despite the inclusion of atomic operations in Hive config.

`UPDATE moviesnames SET prodate = (select to_date(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(prod_date,'dd-MMM-yyyy'))) from moviesnames);`

What's the easiest way to achieve the above using Hive-SQL? By copying and transforming a column or an entire table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE moviesnames SET prodate = to_date(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(prod_date,'dd-MMM-yyyy')));
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this way, here is the error message I get. Maybe the problem is in the table structure itself?
`org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10297]: Attempt to do update or delete on table default.moviesnames that does not use an AcidOutputFormat or is not bucketed`

Comment: @uhlik The table should be ORC and bucketed.

Comment: Table is ORC, but I'm not sure how to check if it is bucketed.

Comment: @uhlik DESCRIBE EXTENDED moviesnames

Comment: @uhlik Scenario when you are updating all the table best fit for non-acid INSERT OVERWRITE ... select from itself. But OVERWRITE does not work with ACID tables. Better create new table NOT-ACID, properly bucketed and ORC, insert overwrite into it from your table, then convert to ACID `ALTER TABLE mytable SET TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true');` then remove original one and rename new table

Comment: Complete Table Information is too long for a comment but there seems to be a fragment that contains the desired information, whatever 'numBuckets:-1' means:

`outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat, compressed:false, numBuckets:-1
(...)
{serialization.format=1}), bucketCols:[]`

So it seems to me that the bucketing is off. Is it possible to convert table to bucketed or should a new one be created according to the instructions in the manual?

`https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL+BucketedTables?.`

Comment: @uhlik Yes, create new one, NOT ACID, bucketed, managed, do INSERT OVERWRITE table mytable select ...convert date at the same time. It will work much faster. Check that buckets (files were created) then convert it to ACID.

Comment: As I mentioned, the table was created using the 'Upload Table' tab in Hive View, so I'll try to create it from SQL according to your instructions.